# POO c++ creación de clases

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buenas me gustaría que pudieran darme su ayuda estoy iniciando en programación y estoy en la parte de clases pero no logro hacer que copile tengo que crear la clase animal luego la subclase perro y gato en atributos (Nombre, raza, edad, peso y tamaño) y en métodos (comer y dormir ) y en método comer aplicarle el polimorfismo. En perro en atributo "ladrido frecuente y gato atributo "maullido frecuente".
solo es de imprimir los datos.
No se si esta bien aplicada la creación de las clases

```
class Animal{   
private: 
    
    string nombre;
    string raza;
    int edad;
    float peso;
    float tamano;
    
    public:
        
    string comer;
    string dormir;
    
    Persona(string, int, float); 
    virtual void comer();  
 }; 
class Perro:public Animal{
private: 
string ladrido_frecuente;

public: 
Alumno(string, int, float);
virtual void comer();
};
class Gato:public Animal{
private:
    string maullido_frecuente;
    
public:
    Profesor(string, int, string);
    virtual void comer();   
};
Animal::Animal(string _nombre,string_raza, int _edad,float_peso,float tamano){
   
    nombre=_nombre;
    raza=_raza;
    edad=_edad;
    peso=:_peso;
    tamano=_tamano;}

void Animal::comer(){
cout<<"NOMBRE "<<nombre<<endl;
cout<<"RAZA "<<nombre<<endl;
cout<<"EDAD "<<edad<<endl;
cout<<"PESO En Libras"<<nombre<<endl;
cout<<"TAMAÑO En Centimetros"<<edad<<endl;
}

void Perro::Perro(string _nombre,string_raza, int _edad,float_peso,float tamano){

    nombre=_nombre;
    raza=_raza;
    edad=_edad;
    peso=:_peso;
    tamano=tamano;      
}

 void Gato::Gato(string _nombre,string_raza, int _edad,float_peso,float tamano){

 nombre=_nombre;
    raza=_raza;
    edad=_edad;
    peso=:_peso;
    tamano=tamano
}

int main()
{

 Animal  *vector[2];
 vector[0]=new Alumno("Perro", "Doberman",20, 180.4,40);
 vector[1]=new Alumno("Perro", "Angora",14, 15.1,20);
 vector[0]->comer();
 cout<<"\n";
 vector[1]->comer();
 cout<<"\n";
 vector[2]->comer();
 system("pause");
 return 0;  
 }
```

Comment: `string_raza` corrige por `string _raza`, hay varias variables con este problema.

Comment: `peso=:_peso;` corrige por `peso= _peso;`, también las clases dentro de clases están mal estructuradas (si no me equivoco)... o quizás sea por un mal cierre en las llaves.

Comment: ¿Por qué llamaste los constructores diferente a las clases? ¿No es eso lo que no deja que compile? Por cierto. Estás recibiendo los parámetros por valor. Si bien está optimizado, consume más tiempo y memoria que pasar una referencia constante (`const string &ref`).

Answer (score 1):

Si vamos a tu declaración de `Animal`:

```
class Animal{   
private: 
    
    string nombre;
    string raza;
    int edad;
    float peso;
    float tamano;
    
    public:
        
    string comer;  // <<--- 3, 4
    string dormir; // <<--- 4
    
    Persona(string, int, float); // <<--- 1, 2
    virtual void comer();
 };
```

Vemos varios problemas:

1. La clase se llama `Animal`, no `Persona`. Hay que corregir el nombre del constructor
2. El constructor recibe 3 parámetros mientras que la clase tiene 5 variables miembro privadas ... faltan parámetros en esa declaración.
3. No puedes llamar a una variable igual que una función.
4. Las variables miembro no deberían ser púbicas
5. **IMPORTANTE**: Para evitar fugas de memoria al usar polimorfismo, el destructor de la clase base debería ser **SIEMPRE** virtual

Entiendo que esperan que la clase la definas así:

```
class Animal{   
private: 
    
    string nombre;
    string raza;
    int edad;
    float peso;
    float tamano;
    
public:
        
    Animal(string nombre, string raza, int edad, float peso, float tamano); 
    virtual ~Animal();

    virtual void comer();
    virtual void dormir();
};
```

Las subclases `Perro` y `Gato` podrían quedar así:

```
class Perro : public Animal
{
public:
    Perro(string raza, int edad, float peso, float tamano);
    ~Perro() override;

    void comer() override;
    void dormir() override;
};
```

Es importante marcar las funciones como `override` las funciones que sobreescriban funcionalidad de clases base. De esta forma el compilador te arrojará errores cuando vea que una función no puede sobreescribir a otra (porque no sea virtual la función base, porque la firma no sea la misma, ...).

Otro detalle importante aquí es que en el constructor de las subclases falta el argumento `nombre`. Entiendo que este argumento lo deben proveer las propias subclases.

Vamos con las implementaciones.

Empecemos por los constructores. Aquí vemos como la clase derivada aporta a la clase base el valor de `nombre`:

```
Animal::Animal(string nombre, string raza, int edad, float peso, float tamano)
    : nombre{nombre}
    , raza{raza}
    , edad{edad}
    , peso{peso}
    , tamano{tamano}
{ }

Perro::Perro(string raza, int edad, float peso, float tamano)
    : Animal("perro", raza, edad, peso, tamano)
{ }
```

Los destructores no tienen que hacer nada especial, así que podemos forzar la implementación por defecto. Esto podemos hacerlo de dos maneras diferentes. La primera está disponible únicamente partir del estándar C++11, que vio la luz hace ya 11 años.

```
Animal::~Animal() = default;

Animal::~Animal()
{ }
```

La implementación de las funciones `comer` y `dormir` ya no me queda tan clara por la escasa información que das al respecto. Si se trata de mostrar algo por la consola podría ser algo así:

```
void Animal::comer()
{
    std::cout <<  "El " << nombre << " de raza " << raza << " va a comer\n";
}

void Perro::comer()
{
    std::cout << "Ladrido fuerte!!!\n";

    Animal::comer();    // Invocamos la función de la clase base
}
```

Como la función se sobreescribe en las clases derivadas, al invocar al método `comer` se ejecutará la versión de la clase derivada. Ésta puede, a su vez, invocar a la función de la clase base si así se precisa.

Nota que utilizo `\n` en vez de `std::endl`. `std::endl` es una utilidad que no solo mete un salto de línea. También fuerza a que se vacíe el buffer de salida. No es recomendable utilizarla con alegría ya que vaciar los buffers con mucha frecuencia puede impactar en el rendimiento de las aplicaciones. No es algo que vayas a notar en tu aplicación pero considero que está bien saberlo.